# React Native - State changed in child, how to update Parent?

Tags: react-native

currently i am changing the state in my child component and now i want to update my parent. Initially, i am passing data from the parent to the child then in the child i am changing the state. when i do that nothing happens in app because parent is still not updated, but when i reload the app, the changes that were made are updated.

I am also using react navigation to go from my parent screen to child screen.

Here is my code:

Parent Screen:

```
function PostsScreen({navigation}) {

const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
const [error, setError] = useState(false);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

const loadPosts = async () => {
setLoading(true);
const response = await postsApi.getPosts();
setLoading(false);

if (!response.ok) return setError(true);

setError(false);
setPosts(response.data);
};

useEffect(() => {
loadPosts();
}, []);

return(
<ActivityIndicator visible={loading} />
<FlatList
      data={posts}
      keyExtractor={(post) => post.id.toString()}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <Card
          title={item.title}
          subTitle={item.subTitle}
          onPress={() => 
          navigation.navigate(routes.POST_DETAILS,item)}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
  }
```

Child Screen:

```
function PostDetailsScreen({ route }) {
const post = route.params;
const { user} = useAuth();

const [addedToLikes, setAddedToLikes] = useState(post.isLiked);
const[likesCount,setLikesCount]=useState(post.likesCount)

const addToLikes = (PostId,userId) => {
postsApi.likePost({PostId,userId});
setAddedToLikes(!addedToLikes);
};

let show_likes="";
if(addedToLikes){
show_likes=(likesCount >1)?(("Liked by you")+" and "+(likesCount - 1)+((likesCount ==2)?( " 
other"):(" others"))):("Liked by you");
}else if(likesCount >0){
show_likes=(likesCount ==1)?(likesCount+ " like"):(likesCount + " likes");
}

return(
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {addToLikes(post.id,user.id)}}>
              {addedToLikes?<MaterialCommunityIcons
              name="heart"
            />:<MaterialCommunityIcons
                name="heart-outline"
              />}
</TouchableOpacity>

<View><TextInput>{show_likes}</TextInput></View>

)}
```

How do i update if a post isLiked and likesCount in the parent component?

Also, i am not using Redux.

**Update**:

I tried doing the following but i still keep getting an error.

Parent Screen:

```js
function PostsScreen({ navigation }) {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const loadPosts = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const response = await postsApi.getPosts();
    setLoading(false);

    if (!response.ok) return setError(true);

    setError(false);
    setPosts(response.data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    loadPosts();
  }, []);

  const [addedToLikes, setAddedToLikes] = useState(post.isLiked);

  const addToLikes = (PostId, userId) => {
    postsApi.likePost({ PostId, userId });
    setAddedToLikes(!addedToLikes);
  };

  const { user } = useAuth();

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ActivityIndicator visible={loading} />
      <FlatList
        data={posts}
        keyExtractor={post => post.id.toString()}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <Card
            title={item.title}
            subTitle={item.subTitle}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate(routes.POST_DETAILS, item)}
          />
        )}
      />
      <PostDetailsScreen addToLikes={addToLikes(posts.id, user.id)} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Child Screen:

```js
function PostDetailsScreen({ route, addedToLikes, addToLikes }) {
  const post = route.params;

  const [likesCount, setLikesCount] = useState(post.likesCount);

  let show_likes = "";
  if (addedToLikes) {
    show_likes =
      likesCount > 1
        ? "Liked by you" + " and " + (likesCount - 1) + (likesCount == 2 ? " other" : " others")
        : "Liked by you";
  } else if (likesCount > 0) {
    show_likes = likesCount == 1 ? likesCount + " like" : likesCount + " likes";
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          addToLikes;
        }}
      >
        {addedToLikes ? <MaterialCommunityIcons name="heart" /> : <MaterialCommunityIcons name="heart-outline" />}
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <View>
        <TextInput>{show_likes}</TextInput>
      </View>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using some form of shared state such as Redux the best way to achieve the outcome you're after is to decide on your component structure.

It sounds like you have a structure like this:

Parent (doesn't know about `likes`) -> Child (knows about `likes`)

But you're wanting something like this:

Parent (knows about `likes`) -> Child (interaction with `likes`)

Therefore I recommend having your `state` in the Parent component keep track of `isLiked` and `likesCount`. The parent will also pass down a method handler to the child component such as `addToLikes(post.id,user.id)`.

Example code:

```
import React from 'react';

class Parent extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: null
        }
    }

    handleCallback = (childData) =>{
        this.setState({data: childData})
    }

    render(){
        const {data} = this.state;
        return(
            <div>
                <Child parentCallback = {this.handleCallback}/>
                {data}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class Child extends React.Component{
  
    onTrigger = (event) => {
        this.props.parentCallback("Data from child");
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    render(){
        return(
        <div>
            <form onSubmit = {this.onTrigger}>
                <input type = "submit" value = "Submit"/>
            </form>
        </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Parent;
```

Comment: i have tried a solution where i added my addedToLikes state and addToLikes function inside my parent component but now i keep getting an error when i try to like a post that addToLikes is not a function. I have also tried returning  <PostDetailsScreen isLiked={addToLikes}/> but i also keep getting an error

Comment: i cannot call <Child/> inside my parent it keeps giving me an error

Comment: Please share a codesandbox showing what you tried, and tell us what error you’re getting

Comment: Yeah please share the code in that case, could be related to your usage of the "this" keyboard. That stuff can be quite confusing without seeing code :) cheers

Comment: @AlanP. i have updated my code with the current code i am trying out. Please if you can please have a look.

Comment: @LeslieAlldridge Hi, i have updated my code with the current code i am trying out. Please if you can please have a look. I am also using functional components not class hence i do not use the "this" keyword.

Comment: You can't return two elements/components in a component side-by-side, so I added a few `<React.Fragment>`.  I think there is also a problem with how you are passing down `addToLikes`... you are calling the function right there and passing the result down.  You want to pass down the function so it gets called on click: `<MyComponent onClick={() => {console.log('you will see this when they click');} } />` not `<MyComponent onClick={console.log('you will see this right away') } />`. I also dont see where `post` (from `post.isLiked`) is defined in the parent.